# Should I use do_action in the header file?

Tags: headers, template-include

I have a lot to add on the header file because of if/else condition. And it makes the file very messy. So, I have decided to include another file...

So how to add it:

1. Creating a function file and add it with do_action()
2. Getting a template file get_template_part()

Comment: In which part of header.php? inside <body>? And what exactly do you want to put in there?

Comment: Yes, inside body. For logo and social icons when it is set(custom image) the header with logo will appear differently from not define the custom header image.

Answer (score 0):

In my development experience.
get_template_part() is better way to maintain In the future.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/